# Where clause matches but returns null in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table with data in string format. When I am trying to select all the records that match a specific product id, map reduce runs its job and gives OK iin the end without the actual results. I know for a fact that data pertaining to that product id exists in the table. Where am I going wrong?
My query is

```
select * from tablename where product_id='xxxx';
```

---

#### Solved

I figured out why it was happening. For others facing the same problem, try checking your string format. My product_id was saved as "xxxx" in the file. So while querying, if I did select * from tablename where product_id= '"xxxx"'; it worked. I got rid of those extra quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Often this is because of whitespace which is hard to see, try using trim(product_id) = "xxxx"

Comment: Tried this. Not working. I am not sure why where clause isn't working at all.

Answer (score 0):

To see a bit better if there are white spaces in your content try something like

```
select concat('#',product_id,'#') from tablename where product_id like '#%XXX%#';
```

Answer (score 0):

...I ran into this with some data I inherited, and since I was going to do a lot of operations on the data (and because the table was only in the range of 10k records), I did something to it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE a AS
SELECT 
        regexp_extract(`origin`,  '^.([A-Za-z0-9]*)', 1) as origin,
        regexp_extract(`dest`,  '^.([^"]*)', 1) as dest,
FROM a-gummy
```

The second of the two regular expressions is the most precise. It asks for a string beginning at the second character of the original field that runs as far as the first " character encountered.

In the case where the data set is too large to simply create a second instance of the table, you might use a view created in this fashion.

Comment: By the way. I haven't had a chance to play with it directly (because it's integrated in Hive 0.14 and I'm not using that yet), but it's possible that the CSV Serde will solve this problem directly.  If someone is working with 14 and can suggest an approach, I'd be delighted to see it too.